# how to call the super constructor in a event function

Tags: node.js

When I run this code I want to be printed as "Mohammed said: hi guys"
but it comes to an error
which is #person is not a function. 
Why it is?

```
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');

var person = function(name){
    this.name = name;
};

 util.inherits(person, events.EventEmitter);

var mohammed = new person('mohammed');
var tahir = new person('tahir');
var taha = new person('taha');
var people = ['mohammed', 'tahir', 'taha'];

people.forEach(function(person){
    person.on('speak', function(msg){
        console.log(person.name + 'said:' + msg);
    });
});

mohammed.emit('speak', "Hi guys");
tahir.emit('speak', "i want a chicked");
```

can anyone fix this? and let me know where I am gone wrong and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call an `.on` method on a string in the `people` array.

You'll need to put the `person` objects you've created, not strings, into the `people` array:

```
var people = [mohammed, tahir, taha];
```

instead of

```
var people = ['mohammed', 'tahir', 'taha'];
```